# How do I add the "chilkat" library to my Swift project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, chilkat

I created a new Xcode 10/Swift 5/iOS12 project ("FTPTest") to test the Chilkat [library](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_ios.asp) (obj-c). I know this is probably a stupid question: *How do I add it to my project?*

According to [this](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/chilkatSwiftIos.asp) guide you have to:

1. Add a .h file, in my case it's `FTPTest-Bridging-Header.h` - check
2. Link to the file in "Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - General" - check (`FTPTest/FTPTest-Bridging-Header.h`) - check
3. Link a "libChilkatIos.a" file in the project's Build Phases - ????

There are multiple "libChilkatIos.a" files in the archive I downloaded and "5)" further down the page tells you to create a universal lib with these files with a provided script [here](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_ios.asp).

I just dragged the unzipped "chilkat-9.5.0-ios" folder from the Finder to "Frameworks" in the Project Navigator, then dragged the ".sh" script file to the text field in "Build Phases -> Run Script", which added it as `/Users/myuser/Dev/chilkat-9.5.0-ios/makeUniversalLib.sh`

How do I properly add the obj-c library to my project (I'm guessing that just dragging didn't work) and how do I even run this script? Building the project fails with 2 error messages:

> 'chilkat-9.5.0-macosx-objc/include/CkoJsonObject.h' file not found
>
> Failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FTPTest-fgmhqpmmunyinifhzwdqipvlwkfu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/FTPTest-Bridging-Header-swift_1S76YILUY5B93-clang_2Y7VT4EKQOHHI.pch' for bridging header '/Users/myuser/Dev/Xcode/FTPTest/FTPTest/FTPTest/FTPTest-Bridging-Header.h'

Comment: did you use script to generate universal lib or not? it is in the manual

Comment: Yes, I `dragged the ".sh" script file to the text field in "Build Phases -> Run Script", which added it as /Users/myuser/Dev/chilkat-9.5.0-ios/makeUniversalLib.sh` but I have no idea how to even run it. I tried to run build the app, hoping that that would run the script too but I got the error messages. I'm not even sure if I added the library properly, so if just dragging from the Finder is okay.